# ftp login using jquery dialog form

Tags: jquery, ftp, login-script

I ask for some help/advise.

I have a jquery form dialog to collect usr/pwd in order to do a ftp login.

I have the form working and the dialog is showing me the correct values for the fields but the dialog I have is not working (I am newbie with jquery) nothing happens. My guess is the .ajax but I cannot be sure.

Here is the code I have:

```
$(function(){
  $('#ftp').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'highlight',
    hide: 'scale',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'send': function() {
            var name = $('#usr').val(), password = $('#pwd').val();
            var myftp = $(this);

            if (name != '' && password != '') { // alert('name=' + name + '&pass=' + password);
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'ftp.php',
                  data: 'name='+name+'&pass='+password,
                  success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                    $(myftp).dialog('close');
                  }
                });
            }
        },
        'close': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
    },
    resizable: false,
    width: '500px'
});
```

ftp.php is a simple `header ('location: ... )` to call the ftp with the proper parameters.

`#ftp` is the form id  containing usr/pwd.

I don't know if jquery has the equivalent functionality. I am more familiar with php

I really appreciate your help with this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. Finally I replace ajax and the result is:

```
if (name != '' && password != '') {                  //alert('usr='+name+'&pwd='+password);
    window.parent.location="http://domain.com/ftp.php?" + 'name='+name+'&password='+password;
}
```

I'll try later with $("#myForm").submit() instead to avoid the password travel in the open. But this works as per my own request.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with either jQuery's dialog or PHP's header() but I see a couple of things that you can do that might help you fix this regarding the AJAX request.

Firstly add this after your success function:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
}
```

Secondly, one thing that should not effect the AJAX but will at least make it more readable is to instead define your data parameter as a map rather than a string, like this:

```
data: ({
    name: name,
    pass: password
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:

Instead of ajax I just used window.parent.location as this:

```
if (name != '' && password != '') {               
   window.parent.location="http://domain.com/ftp.php?" + 'usr='+name+'&pwd='+password;
}
```

I'll try later with `$("#myForm").submit()` instead to avoid the password travel in the open. But this works as per my own request.